# animating a Light2D via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script that generates a AnimationCurve assigns it to an AnimationClip, and then plays the clip. the code looks something like this:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.Universal;

public class lighs : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animation anim;
    private AnimationCurve curve;
    private new Light2D light;

    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
        StartCoroutine(ShrinkCR(10));
        light = GetComponent<Light2D>();
    }

    IEnumerator ShrinkCR(float time)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Shrink(anim));
        }
    }
    private float Shrink(Animation anim)
    {
        AnimationClip clip = new AnimationClip
        {
            legacy = true
        };
        Keyframe[] keys;

        keys = new Keyframe[2];
        keys[0] = new Keyframe(0.0f, light.pointLightOuterRadius);
        keys[1] = new Keyframe(1.0f, light.pointLightOuterRadius * 0.5f);
        curve = new AnimationCurve(keys);
        clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Light2D), "pointLightOuterRadius", curve);

        keys = new Keyframe[2];
        keys[0] = new Keyframe(0.0f, light.pointLightInnerRadius);
        keys[1] = new Keyframe(1.0f, light.pointLightInnerRadius * 0.5f);
        curve = new AnimationCurve(keys);
        clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Light2D), "pointLightInnerRadius", curve);

        anim.AddClip(clip, clip.name);
        anim.Play(clip.name);
        return clip.length;
    }
}
```

but when I hit play mode, nothing happens. any idea why that's the case? if such functionality was just not added, any alternative to animate point light inner and outer radius?

[editor animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3h8Z.jpg)

[script animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh98Z.jpg)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Is there anything on the output or logs? errors etc.

Comment: nope, nothing. I noticed that after 10 seconds the Animation component plays a clip animating 2 properties: "Light 2D.Point Light Inner Radius" and "Light 2D.Point Light Outer Radius" which is almost identical to what you would see if you were to animate the light normally from the editor except for a small "C# script" icon missing in the script animation. _See screenshots attached_

Comment: Where are the screenshots? I can't see them in your questions or your comment.

Comment: done, you should be able to see them now

Comment: Ok I can see them now. also check that "console" in the editor and see if there is anything helpful to include in your question to give people a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: I know my question is not supposed to depend on any screenshot but I didn't know how to neglect using them. I hope my question is still clear without them.

Comment: @AntiqTech there is nothing in the console, just a message I print each time there is a collision

Comment: No problem. It's better to give screenshot since it also includes a view of your editor. Maybe someone will spot some setting or value is not what it is supposed to be etc.